# Solution for Summation of this

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I calculate this summation?
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{i+2}{i^2+4i+3}$$
Can you give me sume detail for calculate sigma for any problem?

Comment: try to use latex cause it is difficult to interprate your question

Comment: I hope I did not change the meaning when editing your post to proper $\LaTeX$.

Comment: is i is a complex number?

Comment: @iostream007: I believe it is just an integer index for the summation.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\frac{i+2}{i^2+4i+3} = \frac{i+2}{(i+1)(i+3)} = \frac{A}{i+1} + \frac{B}{i+3} = \frac{1/2}{i+1} + \frac{1/2}{i+3}.
$$
So you get two harmonic series and they both diverge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Since
$$\frac{i+2}{i^2+4i+3}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{i}$$
so your series is divergent by comparaison with harmonic series.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:**
$$
\frac{1}{i^2+4i+3}=\frac12\left(\frac1{i+1}-\frac1{i+3}\right)
$$

**Hint 2:**
$$
i+2=\frac12\big((i+1)+(i+3)\big)
$$

Comment: Hint 2 is probably more direct.

Answer (score 3):

Split the summand into partial fractions and obtain two trailing series of the harmonic series. Hence the infinite sum diverges to $+\infty$.